# Android Java - .getDownloadUrl().toString() in Firebase returns "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@9501820 " how to use this to load the image?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on an android project using firebase for database but i am not able to retrieve the uploaded image as i can't get the url for the image i used .getDownloadUrl() method but it doesn't return the url but com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@9501820.

Comment: This question is incomplete. You should paste at least a small piece of your code, that others users can reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to register a callback on `getDownloadUrl()` like below because it is an instance of `Task`, not `String`. `Task` is asynchronous, you can't just do `toString()` to get an url.

```
dateRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl) {                
           //do something with downloadurl
        } 
    });
```